# The same assembly code with and without (__restrict) in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

I would like to compare the effect of producing assembly code in C++ by Visual Studio with and without __restrict keyword. So, I used the standard C++ example on the Microsoft website as below "https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/cpp/cpp/extension-restrict?view=msvc-160"
The main.cpp file contains:

```
//In main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std::chrono;

int main()
{
    int* a = new int[MAX];
    int* b = new int[MAX];
    int* c = new int[MAX];
    int* d = new int[MAX];
    int n = MAX;
    //initialize a, b, c and d arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        a[i] = (float) i;
        b[i] = (float) i;
        c[i] = (float) i;
        d[i] = (float) i;
    }

    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    sum2(n, a, b, c, d);
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start);
    std::cout << "Time taken by function: " << duration.count() << " microseconds" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The functions.h file contains:

```
#define MAX 1000000
void sum2(int n, int* __restrict  a, int* __restrict  b, int* c, int* d);
```

The functions.cpp file contains:

```
#include "functions.h"

void sum2(int n, int* __restrict  a, int* __restrict b, int* c, int* d) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
        c[i] = b[i] + d[i];
    }
}
```

After compiling the code with /LD flag with and without __restrict keyword, I always see the same assembly code.
I wonder if that means that the compiler does not care about __restrict keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I should use the `/O2` flag when compiling the code. This flag will optimize the code and apply the effect of the `__restrict` keyword.